# Get сurrent URL

Tags: php

Есть ajax форма на которую переходят по ссылке с видео (жалоба), ссылка вида:
`http://site.com/abuse/index.html?ref=https://login.site.com/rest/getPublicStream/id=OA==/code=Nzc2MTIxMzEwNTg=?null`

Мне нужно передать этот урл (для каждого видео он разный).
Я использую:

```
$url1 = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
$url2 = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

но получаю урл такой:

```
site.com/abuse/abuse_mailer.php
```

Как получить нужный мне URL?

Comment: echo $_GET['ref'];

Comment: не выводит ничего, пусто, как в чистом поле.

Answer (score 1):

подумайте.
$_SERVER - это массив.
вы запрашиваете `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` и `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`... 
как нужно обращаться к массиву в PHP?

если HTTP_HOST - это константа (поскольку вокруг нет кавычек), чему она у вас равна?
если это не константа, почему у вас отключено отображение ошибок?

как вы думаете, почему в руководстве http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php все эти значения обрамлены в кавычки?

маленький урок дебага: вы пробовали, например, когда-нибудь, написать `var_dump($_SERVER);` как вы будете обращаться к полям этого массива?

```
$url1 = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; //должно выдать notice, но отображение ошибок отключено
$url2 = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; //same here
```

Answer (score 0):

Обращаетесь
http://site.com/abuse/**index.html**?ref=https://login.site.com/rest/getPublicStream/id=OA==/code=Nzc2MTIxMzEwNTg=?null

а получаете
site.com/abuse/**abuse_mailer.php**

при этом  $_GET['ref'] пустой (он не должен быть пустым. @Firepro прав).

Скорее всего, неправильно настроен htaccess - он обрезает GET запрос.
Исправьте htaccess.

Comment: Спасибо, а в каком направлении хоть копать в htaccess?

Comment: Redirect или RewriteRule. Точно не помню.